# Locating a button from outside its activity

Tags: java, android, button

I have Firebaselistener class and it listens for the value of 1. When this value is reached I want the button drawable to change. Originally I had this all set up in my main activity and it worked OK using:

```
if(dls==1){
m.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.buttonbkground2));
}
```

from with in my main activity using a valueEventlistener and listening for the value.

But now I've set up a class to do the same thing I can't access the button ids from the main activity.

```
public class RewardValueListener  implements ValueEventListener {

FirebaseAuth mAuth;
String userid;
int i;
View view;
String dls;
Button mButton;
Context c;

public RewardValueListener() {

}

@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    userid = user.getUid();
    dls = dataSnapshot.child(userid).child("counter").getValue(String.class);
    Log.d("tag", "Value: " + dls);
    i = Integer.parseInt(dls);
    if (i == 1) {

        Log.d("tag", "Congrats " + i);


        mButton.setBackground(c.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.buttonbkground2));

    }
}
@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

}
```

***Code edit with cricket's answer included

```
  public void getButton(Button button,Context context) {
    mButton = button;
    c=context;
  }
```

I know it's something to do with calling the view but how and where do I call it?

### Edit

Thanks to @cricket_007 for his answer which works great. Now I have the code working is there away to call my Listener class to change all the buttons in my main activity rather than just one.

I can get it to work if for every button if write the code this way but is there a way to condense it so I don't have to overflow my main activity:

```
  RewardValueListener reward1 = new RewardValueListener();
    mListref.child("RewardsSystem").addValueEventListener(reward1);
    reward1.getButton(mstreaming,mcontext);
    RewardValueListener reward2 = new RewardValueListener();
    mListref.child("RewardsSystem").addValueEventListener(reward2);
    reward2.getButton(mcustom,mcontext);
    RewardValueListener reward3 = new RewardValueListener();
    mListref.child("RewardsSystem").addValueEventListener(reward3);
    reward3.getButton(mlauncher,mcontext);
    RewardValueListener reward4 = new RewardValueListener();
    mListref.child("RewardsSystem").addValueEventListener(reward4);
    reward4.getButton(mmovies,mcontext);
  etc etc...
```

Comment: What is the `View view;` used for?

Comment: haha it was code ive tried n it not worked lol just forgot remove

Comment: Well, if you kept it and used correctly, `view.findViewById` would be an option, which is why I asked

Comment: Define a function with button code and call that function from listener

Comment: used correctly? ive just tried view.findbyId and it errors out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add to the constructor.

```
final Button mButton;
final Context mContext;
public RewardValueListener(Context context, Button button) {
    mContext = context;
    mButton = button;
}
```

And use that instead of `findViewById` for the button, and `mContext.getResources()`

Note: you'll need to have a button available when you create this class

Comment: thanks @cricket_007 that worked. how do i reslove the getResources()

Comment: ive added the view and it makes my app crash cricket. ive tryed changing the text of my button and that works so the code its self is right. am i doing something wrong with my view do i need to initalize it some where?

Comment: thanks cricket would this also work for multiple buttons in the same activity  @cricket_007

Comment: If you make a new value listener for each button, then yes

Comment: Regarding your edit, `child("RewardsSystem")` can only hold a single listener, so setting it again and again is not correct, but you should ask about that in a new post

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass the button in as a field into your listener either in constructing it or as a setter.

This should work:

```
public class RewardValueListener  implements ValueEventListener {

FirebaseAuth mAuth;
String userid;
int i;
View view;
String dls;
Button button;
public RewardValueListener(Button button) {
    this.button = button;
}

@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    userid = user.getUid();
    dls = dataSnapshot.child(userid).child("counter").getValue(String.class);
    Log.d("tag", "test before if " + dls);
    i = Integer.parseInt(dls);
    if (i==1){

        Log.d("tag", "test after if " + i);
     button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.buttonbkground2));

    }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

}
```

Comment: have you got an example of what you mean by setter please @Matthew

Comment: Edited comment with answer.

Comment: Good point. You'd need to pass in the drawable as well. Looks like he's accepted the other answer though.

Comment: thanks @MatthewBahr but crickets made more sense sorry