# Reusing a ValueEventListener firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

hi guys i have a ValueEventlistener class that listens for a value of 1 when the value is reached it changes the look of the buttons in my main activity. All works fine. But ive been informed that the way im using the listener is wrong. because i recall the same instance over and over

```
public class getRewards {
Firebase mListref;
 Button mstreaming,mcustom,mlauncher,mmovies;
Context mcontext;

public getRewards(Firebase ListRef, Context context){
    this.mListref = ListRef;
    this.mcontext = context;
}
public void getButtonRewards(Button a,Button b,Button c,Button d){
  this.mstreaming = a;
    this.mcustom = b;
    this.mlauncher = c;
    this.mmovies = d;
```

//HERE IS WHERE I REUSE THE LISTENER IS THIS THE RIGHT WAY TO USE IT??

```
     RewardValueListener reward1 = new RewardValueListener();
    mListref.child("RewardsSystem").addValueEventListener(reward1);
    reward1.getButton(mstreaming,mcontext);
    RewardValueListener reward2 = new RewardValueListener();
    mListref.child("RewardsSystem").addValueEventListener(reward2);
    reward2.getButton(mcustom,mcontext);
    RewardValueListener reward3 = new RewardValueListener();
    mListref.child("RewardsSystem").addValueEventListener(reward3);
    reward3.getButton(mlauncher,mcontext);
    RewardValueListener reward4 = new RewardValueListener();
    mListref.child("RewardsSystem").addValueEventListener(reward4);
    reward4.getButton(mmovies,mcontext);
}
```

}
what is the best way to reuse the listener to change all my buttons instead of just one or doing it the above way?

my Reward listener class

```
public class RewardValueListener  implements ValueEventListener {

FirebaseAuth mAuth;
String userid;
int i;
View view;
String dls;
Button mButton;
Context c;

public RewardValueListener() {

}

@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    userid = user.getUid();
    dls = dataSnapshot.child(userid).child("counter").getValue(String.class);

    i = Integer.parseInt(dls);
    if (i == 1) {

        mButton.setBackground(c.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.buttonbkground2));

    }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

}

public void getButton(Button button,Context context) {
    mButton = button;
    c=context;

}
```

and finally how i call it on my main activity

```
   getRewards checkRewardStatus = new getRewards(mListRef,mContext);
    checkRewardStatus.getButtonRewards(mStreaming,mcustom,mUtil,mplayers);
```

Comment: `child("RewardsSystem")` can only have one listener.

Comment: Also, you [aren't using my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44425319/2308683)?

Comment: yeah im using your code 007 just had to rewrite it slightly as it was making null string error. so i just applied a getbutton void using your method.

Comment: what would you suggest to rectify this problem @cricket_007

Comment: My code would only produce that error if *you* gave a null object in the incorrect location.... Also, those are *setter* methods, not *get* methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want to encapsulate four buttons into a single object.

That would best be done using the `View` that holds them all.

```
public class Rewards {
    private Firebase mListref;
    private final Context mcontext;
    Button mstreaming,mcustom,mlauncher,mmovies;

    public Rewards(Context context, Firebase ref, View rootView){
        this.mListref = ref;
        this.mcontext = context;

        if (rootView != null) {
             this.mstreaming = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.streaming);
            this.mcustom = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.custom);
            this.mlauncher = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.launcher);
            this.mmovies = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movies);
        } 
    }
}
```

How you create this depends on an Activity / Fragment situation, but generally, `new Rewards(getContext(), firebaseRef, getView())`. (Those methods won't all resolve, but I don't know how you are using this.)

Then, same as before, add to the constructor.

```
public class RewardValueListener implements ValueEventListener {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private Rewards mRewards;

    public RewardValueListener(Rewards rewards) {
        this.mRewards = rewards; 
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        Integer counter = dataSnapshot.child(userid).child("counter").getValue(Integer.class);

        if (counter == 1) {
            // mRewards.mstreaming.setBackground( ... );  
        } else if (counter == 2) {
            // mRewards.mcustom.setBackground( ... ); 
        }
    }
```

Not sure what conditions your buttons are expected to be changing.

And to wrap-up.

```
View rootView = getView(); // TODO: Implement this somehow
Rewards rewards = new Rewards(mContext, mListref, rootView);
RewardValueListener listener = new RewardValueListener(rewards);
mListref.child("RewardsSystem").addValueEventListener(listener);
```

---

In an Activity, you don't really need a method, and can instead use this

```
View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

Comment: omg cricket are you really that awesome? thank you m8. your name should have been matrix lol. i will try this and get back to you with the result.. i will also change the getter to setter lol

Comment: Ha, it's just Java basics, really. Encapsulation and wrapper objects

Comment: im struggling with the rootView = getView(); which view do i need to pass in? would this be a getter rather than a setter? @cricket_007

Comment: Again, the situation depends how and where you have that line of code. Activity or Fragment?

Comment: its in my main activities onCreate it checks the firebase for a value and then changes the colour of the buttons accordingly. 1 points is a blue drawable with a gradient.

Answer (score 0):

```
public View getView(){
View v;
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlmain);
lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,etSearch);

v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttons, null);
mStreaming = (Button)v. findViewById(R.id.btnStreamingapps);
mcustom = (Button)v.  findViewById(R.id.btncustom);
mUtil = (Button)v.  findViewById(R.id.btnutil);
mplayers = (Button)v.  findViewById(R.id.btnplayers);
 rl.addView(v,lp);


return v;
}
```

this was what i did for getview() @cricket_007 
is there away to make a listview which is in the main activity go below this view at the moment it goes through it lol

Comment: Tagging people in answers doesn't work, by the way. It's great that you learn how to dynamically create a view, but it may not have been necessary. Also, in my answer, you would have passed `v` directly into the `Rewards` class instead of using `v.findViewById` right where you have it

Comment: so i dont need the v?

Comment: It depends how you use it. See the bottom of my answer

Comment: thanks dude removed v and working great still.. thank you for your help dude seriously